How does the magnetic field get confined into a magnetic circuit?
I have this doubt that needs to be solved.
Very quickly: how does the magnetic field stay confined into the toroidal element that is seen in
A? Let's consider it to be made of iron.
How does it bend? I know there is an huge difference in permeability, but that would only make the magnetic field stronger, as shown (very badly) in Figure B.
Is there an effect related to the adjacent elements that steer the magnetic field? How could I wriet it down such a field by usign the Maxwell's equations?
I can't figure it out. Why does the field not only enhance but also bend?
Thank you to anyone who'll try to solve my doubt.

To understand the situation, visualize what happens in a permanent magnet. As you know, electrons have two fields built up around them, they are magnetic dipoles and also have an electric field. In permanent magnets, the magnetic dipoles of the subatomic particles are partially aligned in the same direction and have a self-holding induction (below the Curie temperature).
If you wrap a current-carrying wire around a magnetizable rod, a magnetic field is created in the wire, again due to the self-induction of the magnetic field components of the moving electrons. This external field causes the alignment of the subatomic particles in the rod, very similar to a permanent magnet.
If particles in the rod are magnetically aligned along the rod axis and form a macroscopic field, then the magnetic flux must be returned via the air outside the rod. This is because a magnetic field - whether as a magnetic dipole of the electron or as a macroscopic field - has closed contours. Nature has determined it this way, magnetic monopoles do not exist in our environment.
If you wrap a current-carrying wire around a torus, you have done nothing other than bend the rod and eliminate the return of the field via the air.

how does the magnetic field stay confined into the toroidal element

The induced magnetic field is trapped and is not. Every magnetic field has a saturation. This has to do with the carriers of the field, the subatomic particles. They are only finitely present in a material. So if you generate an external field that is too large, you will also be able to detect a magnetic field outside the torus.
If you proceed “moderately”, it is only sufficient for the magnetic alignment of the electrons in the torus and your magnetic field is fixed in the torus. If you take two windings, you get the most beautiful transformer. If your core is too small, your power losses will increase.
